# How to make exact rounding of control ios?

Tags: ios, swift

I need to make perfect round of the `UIView`. When I try to make it perfect Its not looking like I exactly want.

Which is good to make it by Interface Builder or code?

```
viewRound.layer.cornerRadius = 45.0

viewRound.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Comment: The view has to be a square (same width/same height), and the cornerRadius value has to be the width/2. (or height, since it's a square). Also, check the viewRound frame after viewDidLayoutSubviews, with constraints and all it may not of the size you think of.

Comment: how does it look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply two line of code:

```
viewRound.layer.cornerRadius = viewRound.frame.size.height/2
viewRound.clipsToBounds = true
```

Make sure you are using same height and width like:

**For example**, if your view size is (10*10),(50*50),(100*100), etc. then your view becomes perfect squire else not

Here **Auto Layout** also matters.

Answer (score 0):

It will work.

```
 yourview.layer.cornerRadius = yourView.frame.height/2
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be perfectly round by rounding corners only if your view is a perfect square. If it is rectangular, you will need to use an elliptic shape layer

```
let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
shapeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: yourView.bounds)
shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.black.cgColor;
yourView.layer.mask = shapeLayer;
```